# Why does light and heat yield different stereochemistry in electrocyclic reactions?

Tags: organic-chemistry

In my organic chemistry II class, we started learning about electrocyclic reactions. We learned heat and light yield different products. So my question is, how do they work differently to yield those different products?

Comment: The explanation may be a bit too long here. You should look up how the symmetry of the HOMO and LUMO impact how pericyclic reactions unfold.

Comment: Have a look at Woodward-Hoffman rules.